# Python 3.6 -- sorted set of tuple

Tags: python, sorting

I need to sort my list in alphabetical order but ignore the case of my letters.

```
my_list = [('CAT', 1), ('Crop', 1), ('PoP', 4), ('anTs', 1), ('apple', 1), ('cAt', 1), ('can', 1), ('dog', 1), ('long', 1), ('poeT', 1), ('toe', 2)]
```

I would like to receive :

```
my_list_sorted = [('anTs', 1), ('apple', 1), ('can', 1), ('CAT', 1), ('cAt', 1), ('Crop', 1), ('dog', 1), ('long', 1), ('poeT', 1), ('PoP', 4), ('toe', 2)]
```

I tried to do :

```
sorted(set(my_list),key=str.lower())
```

But I received this error :

```
TypeError: descriptor 'lower' of 'str' object needs an argument
```

Someone can help me please ?

Thank you,
Jason

Comment: Is there a way without using lambda?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide a key function:

```
sorted(my_list, key=lambda item : item[0].lower())
```

Answer (score 8):

This should work:

```
sorted(my_list, key=lambda x: x[0].casefold())
```

The `key` parameter of the function `sorted` is the value that will be used for comparison in the sorting process. In this case the `key` we want is the string part of the tuples in lowercase, so that's what we return using a one-line lambda function.

In python `str` is a basic built in function that converts the value passed to a string, that's why the error.

See [`str.casefold()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold) to understand why is prefered over `str.lower()`

Comment: @MitchelPaulin that's correct -- what would you expect to do?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to keep an original version of the list it's quicker to sort in place by calling a list method:

```
my_list.sort(key=lambda tup: tup[0].lower())
```

this method doesn't return anything because the original list object now becomes sorted.